# como faço para verificar de um arquivo texto esta vazio em php e se estiver termina a execução?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

tenho um codigo que executa uma query simples assim

```
select * from tabela where coluna1 = 'valor';
```

depois tenho uma variavel que trás um arquivo txt

```
$filename = "C:/Programfile/arquivo.txt";
```

e depois faço essa condição abaixo

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    rename($filename,$filename.".old");
}
$file = fopen($filename,"a+");
```

após isso faço o while da query

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
            $content  = $row[0];
            $content .= "\r";
            $content .= "\n";   

            $result = fputs($file,$content);        

//break;
}
fclose($file);
```

o resultado da query vai pra dentro do arquivo texto usando vbs só que eu estou com um problema que quando a query não tem registro o arquivo texto fica vazio e eu não estou conseguindo para a execução do script quando a query não retorna registro alguém pode me ajudar

já tentei fazer isso e não deu certo

```
if(filesize($filename)){
   exit;
}
```

ou no lugar do exit já pus `return false e die()` e não deu certo.

Comment: já resolvi o problema